# Rails Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm having no end of trouble with my Rails 3 app's Mysql connection, though I have studied countless relevant threads. My error message:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (Mysql2::Error)
```

(Before you flag this as a duplicate question, consider whether you can find another thread with pertinent advice I have not followed.)

**My efforts thus far:**

I have copied the libmysql.dll file from `<mysql installation>/bin` to `<ruby installation>/bin`.

I have the mysql2 gem in the bundle, and it was installed with the connector (`--with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32`):

```
> bundle show mysql2
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32
```

I believe my database.yml file is configured correctly:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: tq_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: pinney
  host: localhost
```

Comment: can you connect/run mysql on the command line? (or whatever tools you may use in this Windows thing?). Is MySQL set up to start by itself or do you have to start it manually (as far as I remember this was somehow an option on Win). [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) lists a few steps to check if basics are working.

Comment: What port are you running mysql on? When you do mysql --help on the command line what's the output?

Comment: Yes, I can. mysqld.exe is running as a process and mysql is running as a service.

Comment: @Leo Correa It's the default port 3306.

Comment: Can you try adding a port: 3306 field on the yml file? That's the default port for mysql.

Comment: I just tried it, same error.

Comment: try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 (in workbench and yml)

Comment: That did it! Thanks @Richlewis! Could you make that an Answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 (in workbench and yml)

Comment: Wow that was it. Why doesn't Ruby know what 'localhost' means? I mean that's just standard! Ruby is so dumb.

Comment: Not a Ruby problem, that's the way MySQL works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran rake db:create yet on the project in question?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above....Make sure it works with workbench or some other GUI tool and you can connect using the info the database.yml file.

If not....come back and give us another holler.